# Rails + Chartkick: How to change the date format of the tooltip?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-visualization, chartkick

I am generating the chart (with using Google Chart) this way:

```
  <%=
    area_chart [{:name => "Sold items", data: @items.group(:created_at).count}], :library => {hAxis: {title: "Period"}, vAxis: {title: "Amounts in UDS"}, title: "History Of Sales"}  
  %>
```

And the chart is nicely generated, but there's one thing that I am trying to change - the tooltip looks like this:
[image]

Information in the tooltip are correct, but instead of displaying **Oct 19, 2014, 2:00:00 AM** I would love to display only **Oct 19, 2014**.

Is there any way to do it with Chartkick?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

This works for the x axis:

```
<%= line_chart @model.group(:created_at).count, library: { hAxis: { format: 'MM/dd' } } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the ruby to change the datetime key into require formats.  Example:

```
@items.group("created_at").count.map {|k,v| {k.strftime("%b %d, %Y") => v }}
```